# Wordpress - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function has_package() on null

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the Wordpress theme Reality by inwavethemes. First I was getting this error on my posts page:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in
> /public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 716

Which I fixed by going into the database and making the ID column for wp_posts auto increment.

Now I am getting a new error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function has_package()
> on null

And here is the full error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function has_package() on null in /home/customer/www/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/iwproperty/includes/class/property.class.php:560 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/iwproperty/includes/admin/property.class.php(392): IWP_Property->get_package_id() #1 /home/customer/www/mywebsite/public_html/wp-admin/includes/template.php(1389): IWP_Admin_Property::publish_metabox_html(Object(WP_Post), Array) #2 /home/customer/www/mywebsite/public_html/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php(679): do_meta_boxes(Object(WP_Screen), 'side', Object(WP_Post)) #3 /home/customer/www/mywebsite/public_html/wp-admin/post-new.php(75): require('/home/customer/...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/customer/www/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/iwproperty/includes/class/property.class.php on line 560
There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
```

I took a look at line 560 in property.class.php and this is what it is:

```
if($author->has_package()){
     $package_id = $author->get_package_id();
}else{
     $package_id = (int)get_post_meta($this->get_id(), IWP_PREFIX.'package_id', true);
}
```

Did making the ID column A_I cause this error? How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: `Call to a member function has_package() on null` author is null. You don't show how you've created it.

Comment: I am not creating a post...yet, this error occurs when I goto the Add Post page.

Comment: Why wasn't `wp_posts->ID` already set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the first place? You might have a problem elsewhere

Comment: did you try and updateded to plugin "iwproperty", when not, try in the support forum on the plugin site

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: You should show how to get `$author` from the database.
Please share your more code

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the issue is not related to the auto-increment for the ID column of the wp_posts table. You should debug deeply.
You didn't provide enough information for us to guess the reason for the issue.

But, from the fact the auto-increment was not set up for the ID column, I guess it might be the database issue.

I think you migrated the site from somewhere else, and there was a problem with the database setup.
If this is the case, please try to reinstall the database or check the tables before you check the code.

Comment: And if this solution doesn't work, contact me directly so that I can help you to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be hard for anyone here to answer this without more context especially that the theme you've mentiond is not freely and publicly available for people to inspect. To get past the current error, though, you can add an `isset()` call to the snippet you've shared:

```php
if(isset($author) && $author->has_package()){
  $package_id = $author->get_package_id();
}else{
  $package_id = (int)get_post_meta($this->get_id(), IWP_PREFIX.'package_id', true);
}
```

It perhaps still is a better idea to contact the theme providers directly for support, but in case you decide to patch things up by this change, you should be aware of these two caveats:

- This is just patching the surface and there's a good chance you encounter more errors because of the underlying issue(s).
- Because you're directly updating the theme files, your changes will be overwritten if you update the theme in future.